# Pass data from Tablet application to PC using USB

Tags: android, serial-port, usb, android-3.0-honeycomb, libusb

**I have to communicate from tablet to PC using USB**. I have studied about using `TCP` and `abd` but i have to do with the `Serial port`. I am even not sure is that possible or not. So please guide me through what is the way to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a USB to UART bridge device to do this, but the caveat is that your tablet device will need a driver to do so. Your tag shows you are using Android, which is based on the Linux kernel. Linux already supports plenty of USB to UART bridge devices natively, so once you choose one you can go through the steps of building in the driver to your Android image and probably perform a `make menuconfig` and add in support for your driver that way.

Communication to the PC on the other side of the bridge can be through a standard RS232 serial port (if available), or you can use USB to UART bridge on the other side as well.